# How subtract value of one column based on another column, grouped by other columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to get difference between two values (newest minus oldest) grouped by ISIN and variable. For example,
for variable `a` and `b` I should get -1 and for variable `c` I should get 11.

```
   check = pd.DataFrame({
        'date':[1,2,1,2,1,2],
        'ISIN':[1,1,2,2,3,3],
        'variable':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],
        'value':[8,9,8,9,21,10]    
    })
    result = check.groupby(['ISIN', 'variable'])['value'].apply(lambda x: check.loc[x.idxmax(), 'value'] - check.loc[x.idxmin(), 'value']).reset_index()
```

This is the best I got, but it shows only positive values, because this is how `idxmax()`/`idxmin()` work. Is there a way to group and then subtract values with most recent date minus latest date?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

check = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': [1,2,1,2,1,2],
    'ISIN': [1,1,2,2,3,3],
    'variable': ['a','a','b','b','c','c'],
    'value': [8,9,8,9,21,10]    
})

result = check.groupby(['ISIN', 'variable'])['date'].apply(
    lambda x: check.loc[x.idxmin(), 'value'] - check.loc[x.idxmax(), 'value']
).reset_index()
result.columns = ['ISIN', 'variable', 'value']
print(result)
```

Which gives the output:

```
   ISIN variable  value
0     1        a     -1
1     2        b     -1
2     3        c     11
```

This version applies the `idxmin` and `idxmax` on the `date`, rather than on the `value`.

Your original applied it to the `value`, so in that case, the value would always be positive (since it would always subtract the minimum from the maximum).

I also switched around the `idxmin` and `idxmax` to achieve the intended output - you seem to have had it the opposite way around, which would negate the results.